# Use SignalR with IP Address instead of computer name

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, signalr

I have a SignalR service setup to run self hosted in a Windows Service.

When I enter this address:

> http://mycomputer.mydomain.net:8789/signalr/signalr/negotiate

I get some xml (for negotiation) displayed in the browser (showing that hit the service correctly.)

But if I enter this address (that has `mycomputer.mydomain.net`'s ip address in place of the computer name):

> http://10.92.15.6:8789/signalr/signalr/negotiate

or this

> http://localhost:8789/signalr/signalr/negotiate

I get this error:

> Bad Request - Invalid Hostname
>
> HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.

I have tried also using:

> http://10.92.15.6.mydomain.net:8789/signalr/signalr/negotiate

But I just get:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> 10.92.15.6.mydomain.net’s server DNS address could not be found.

**Is there someway to be able to make SignalR work using an IP Address instead of the computer name?**

Answer (score 4):

I had to change my startup from this:

```
string url = "http://" + machineName + ".mydomain.net:8789";
server = WebApp.Start<Startup>(url);
```

to this:

```
string url = "http://*:8789";
var startOptions = new StartOptions(url);
server = WebApp.Start<Startup>(startOptions);
```